# Activating extension ' failed: Cannot find module 'file.js' when keeping /out in .gitignore

Tags: vscode-extensions

while vs code extension development, there is **/out** folder which keep generated js files for respective typescript file but committing these files in remote repo seems not useful so adding the entry in `.gitignore` but now when I run the extension it say module not found

```bash
Activating extension 'xkeshav.<extension-name>' failed: Cannot find module 'd:\Developer\extension-folder\out\extension.js'
Require stack:
- c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js
- c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-amd.js
- c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-fork.js
- .
```

so my question is

when not keeping /out entry in .gitignore, it works file so whether we need to commit these files in remote or not ?

Comment: You will have to share more details on your extension, so mine with the same `.gitignore` does not experience the same issue, https://github.com/vscode-restructuredtext/vscode-restructuredtext/blob/190.1.4/.gitignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a .vscodeignore file in your repo. VS Code only uses .gitignore if there's no .vscodeignore. The .vscodeignore file is then used to exclude files/folders from the extension bundle instead of .gitignore. A typical .vscodeignore looks like this:

```
.vscode/**
.vscode-test/**
out/test/**
test/**
src/**
images/**
**/*.map
.gitignore
.eslintignore
.eslintrc.json
tsconfig.json
typings/**
```

As you see `out/` itself is not excluded, just the tests which end up there.